# Getting error DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When i run the `help` command it says `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; //if a bot return 
    if (!message.guild) return;     //if not in a guild return
    
    let prefix = await db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)//getting prefix 
    if (prefix === null) prefix = config.PREFIX;           //if not prefix set it to standard prefix in the config.json file
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); //arguments of the content
    const command = args.shift();                                          //defining the command msgs

    if (message.content.includes(client.user.id)) { //if message contains musicium as a ping
       return message.reply(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("#fffff0").setAuthor(`${message.author.username}, My Prefix is ${prefix}, to get started; type ${prefix}help`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),"https://harmonymusic.tk"));
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) { //if its a command react with a random emoji
        let random = getRandomInt(8);         //get the actual random number
        message.react(emojis[random]);        //react with the emoji
    }
    else { //if not a command skip
        return; 
    }
///////////////////
/////COMMANDS//////
///////////////////
try{

    if (command === "invite" || command === "add"){
        return embedbuilder(client, message, "#fffff0", "Invite me!", "[`Click here`](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client id here } &permissions=49572160&scope=bot)   |   [`Website`](https://harmonymusic.tk)   |   :heart: Thanks for inviting!")
         }
    if (command === "radio") {
        return radio(client, message, args); //get the radio module
    }
    if (command === "p" || command === "play"){
      message.channel.send('done')
    }
    if (command === "help"  || command === "about" || command === "h" || command === "info") {
        let helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#fffff0")
        .setTitle("**__COMMANDS__**")
        .setThumbnail("https://c.tenor.com/5FmfYNNPcwQAAAAC/dance-music.gifU")
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}),"https://harmonymusic.tk")
        .setFooter(client.user.username + " | Syntax:  <>...must    []...optional", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`
        **Prefix:** \`${prefix}\`   *change with:* \`${prefix}prefix <NEW PREFIX>\`

        \`${prefix}help\`  \`${prefix}h\` **>** List of all Commands
        \`${prefix}play <URL/NAME>\`  \`${prefix}p\` **>** Plays a song
        \`${prefix}radio [radiostation]\` **>** Plays a radiostation
        \`${prefix}status\` **>** Shows queue status
        \`${prefix}nowplaying\`  \`${prefix}np\` **>** Shows current song
        \`${prefix}pause\` **>** Pauses the song
        \`${prefix}resume\`  \`${prefix}r\` **>** Resume the song
        \`${prefix}shuffle\`  \`${prefix}mix\` **>** Shuffles the queue
        \`${prefix}playskip\`  \`${prefix}ps\` **>** Plays new song and skips current
        \`${prefix}autoplay\`  \`${prefix}ap\` **>** Enables autoplay - random similar songs
        \`${prefix}skip\`  \`${prefix}s\` **>** Skips current song
        \`${prefix}stop\`  \`${prefix}leave\` **>** Stops playing and leaves the channel
        \`${prefix}seek <DURATION>\` **>** Moves in the Song in: seconds
        \`${prefix}volume <VOLUME\`  \`${prefix}vol\` **>** Changes volume
        \`${prefix}queue\`  \`${prefix}qu\` **>** Shows current Queue
        \`${prefix}loop <0/1/2>\`  \`${prefix}mix\` **>** Enables loop for off / song / queue
        \`${prefix}lyircs\`  \`${prefix}ly\` **>** Shows lyrics for this song
        \`${prefix}jump <Queue num.>\` **>** Jumps to a queue song
        \`${prefix}prefix <PREFIX>\` **>** Changes the prefix
        \`${prefix}ping\` **>** Gives you the ping
        \`${prefix}uptime\` **>** Shows you the Bot's Uptime
        `)
        .addField("***FILTER COMMANDS:***",`
        \`${prefix}gate\` | \`${prefix}haas\` | \`${prefix}pulsator\` | \`${prefix}surrounding\` | \`${prefix}clear\` | \`${prefix}8d\` | \`${prefix}bassboost\` | \`${prefix}echo\` | \`${prefix}karaoke\` | \`${prefix}nightcore\` | \`${prefix}vaporwave\` | \`${prefix}flanger\` | \`${prefix}subboost\` | \`${prefix}phaser\` | \`${prefix}tremolo\` | \`${prefix}vibrato\` | \`${prefix}reverse\` | \`${prefix}treble\` | \`${prefix}clear\`   
        `)
        .addField("***SUPPORTED SOURCES:***",`
        \`Youtube\`, \`Soundcloud\`, [\`More\`](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), ...
        `)
        .addField("***BOT BY:***",`
        <@852848188942581764> \`hmm\`
        `)
        .addField("***SUPPORT:***",`
        [\`Server\`](https://discord.gg/)
        `)
        message.channel.send(helpembed)
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please check the value of `helpembed`, `` is it there?

Answer (score 0):

In `discord.js` v13, you can't directly send embeds in the `.send()` function. You need to specify that they are embeds by adding `.send({ embeds: [helpembed] })` since `discord.js` thinks that the `helpembed` variable is a string and when it is not able to send it as a string, it raised the error. Your final code might look something like this:

```js
if (command === "help"  || command === "about" || command === "h" || command === "info") {
    let helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // ...
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [helpembed] })
    return;
}
```